# Airflow: How to implement Dynamic html_content

Tags: airflow

I need to implement the html_content dynamic for custom email operator, as we have html_content different for different jobs.

Also, I need the values, for example, `rows` and `filename` be dynamic

The example below is one of the email body:

```
  The `filename` has been delivered.  `0 rows` for contact from 2020-06-14. If you have any questions or concerns regarding this feed please reply to this email

    NOTE: The information contained in this email message is considered confidential and proprietary to the sender and is intended solely for review and use by the named recipient. Any unauthorized review, use, or distribution is strictly prohibited. If you have received this message in error, please advise the sender by reply email and delete the message.
```

Code:

```
def execute(self, context):

        if self.source_task_ids:
            ti = context['task_instance']
            self.s3_key = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=self.source_task_ids, key='s3_key')[0]

        self.s3_key = self.get_s3_key(self.s3_key)
        s3_hook = S3Hook(self.s3_conn_id)

        try:
            if not s3_hook.check_for_key(self.s3_key, bucket_name=self.s3_bucket):
                logger.info(f'The source key {self.s3_key} does not exist in the {self.s3_bucket}')
                rowcount = 0
                self.subject  = self.subject
                self.html_content = self.html_content
            else:
                filedata = s3_hook.read_key(self.s3_key, bucket_name=self.s3_bucket)
                rowcount = filedata.count('\n') - 1
                logger.info(f'rowcount: {rowcount}')
                self.subject = self.subject
                self.html_content = self.html_content
            self.snd_mail(self.send_from,self.send_to,self.subject, self.html_content, self.eml_server, files=self.files)
        except Exception as e:
            raise AirflowException(f'Error in sending the Email - {e}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow support [Jinja templating](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) in operators. It is build into the BaseOperator and controlled by the `template_fields` and `template_ext` fields of the base operator, e.g.:

```
class CustomEmailOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ("html_content")
    template_ext = (".html",)

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, html_content, ...):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.html_content = html_content

    def execute(self, context):
      # Rest of operator code, nothing special needs to happen to render the templates
```

Now the html_content field can either be a path to a jinja templated file with the `.html` extension or a html string directly. Parameters can be passed to the Jinja template using the `params` field of the operator:

```
task1 = CustomEmailOperator(
    task_id = "task1",
    html_content = "Hello, {{ params.name }}",
    params = {
        "name": "John",
    },
    ...
)
```

That is how you could pass the filename and # of rows parameters. If you do not want to rely on the BaseOperator mechanism to template your email content, e.g. because you need a bit more control you can also use a helper function available in Airflow:

```
from airflow.utils.helpers import parse_template_string

html_content = "Hello, {{ params.name }}"
_, template = parse_template_string(html_content)
body = template.render({"name": "John"})
```